# Get HostName for Each RemoteAddress IP in New Member

Tags: windows-10, powershell, powershell-5.0

I have a PowerShell script, which has some variables

1. `$GetCon` : Get Tcp Connection in Powershell
2. `$hn` : Get expand Remote-Address in `$GetCon`.
3. `$rrt` : is a Number of all results, it's all connection IP's.
4. `$GNamess` : is a variable to Create a new Member by name (**urls**) for `$GetCon` which is a Get-NetTCPConnection.

**Finally** I have a new member, it will be contain list of each Connections Host Names for Each IP Address in Get-TCPConnection RemoteAddress.

**But** we don't revive result of host's in the result, in the result I've one Host for each host's.

please get me an method to get all host's in the result.

**Wrong Syntax:**

```
$GetCon = Get-NetTCPConnection

$hn = $GetCon | select -expand RemoteAddress

$rrt = foreach ($IPs in $hn)
{

 [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($IPs) | select-object IPAddressToString -expandproperty  IPAddressToString

}


$GNamess = foreach ($IPst in $GetCon) {

    $rrt = ([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostbyAddress($IPs) | select-object HostName -expandproperty  HostName)
    $IPst | Add-Member -NotePropertyName urls -NotePropertyValue $rrt -PassThru
}

$GetCon | select urls
```

**Image Result:**
[Image Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov5Ye.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for comment and hard to guess your aim from your code so maybe creating an filling dictionary `$IPsNames` could help?

```
$IPsNames = @{}

$GetCon = Get-NetTCPConnection

$hn = $GetCon | select -expand RemoteAddress  | sort -Unique

foreach ( $IPs in $hn ) {

    try   { $rrtx = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostbyAddress($IPs).HostName }
    catch { $rrtx = '???' }

    $IPsNames[ $IPS ] = $rrtx
}

### $IPsNames

for ( $i = 0; $i -lt $GetCon.Count; $i++ ) {

    $aux = $IPsNames[ $GetCon[$i].RemoteAddress ]
    $GetCon[$i] | Add-Member -NotePropertyName urls -NotePropertyValue $aux 

}

### $GetCon | Format-Table -Property RemoteAddress, urls -AutoSize

$GetCon | selelect -Property RemoteAddress, urls
```

Comment: Thank yo @JosefZ to help our errors. 
this helpful for me, but I want to Add new Member to $GetCon variable.
I have a Wrong syntax with your Right syntax:
$Rem = $IPsNames.Values
$GetCon | select urls
...
Please also fix this for me. thank you

Comment: @SchoolforDesign answer updated (possible approach).

Comment: Thank you my bro, it's very helpful for me...
@JosefZ Can I ask something else?

Comment: @SchoolforDesign Of course, you can ask here for a minor specification… although… [this strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657595/proper-syntax-powershell-error-for-missing-parenthesis-but-only-6-parenthesis-i/41657767?noredirect=1#comment70533644_41657767) _could_ be a more effective way for you as StackExchage sites are not chat-like ones, ultimately. If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.

Comment: Of course @JosefZ, your answer is very helpful, sorry for forgetting an accepted you answer.
(1)
my other question is:
i have a HTML - table on my powershell which is imported some case or some aliases such as port, ipaddress..etc.
and i have an HTML <div> tag which contain nothing yet! 
i want to add some information embeded in $GetCon which is my Aliases.

Comment: (2)
, i want to add for example:
when I click first row in table, which contain IP(127.0.0.1), the <div> containing a 'localhost'. and so on for each oter table rows.
thank you again.

Answer (score -2):

```
<# Report = LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,FQDN,RemotePort,PID,ProcessName,UserName,State,CreationTime #>

$obj=@()

Foreach($p In (Get-Process -IncludeUserName | where {$_.UserName} | `
 select Id, ProcessName, UserName)) {
 $properties = @{ 'PID'=$p.Id;
 'ProcessName'=$p.ProcessName;
 'UserName'=$p.UserName;
 }
 $psobj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $properties
 $obj+=$psobj
 }

$Connections = Get-NetTCPConnection | where {$_.State -ne "Listen" -and $_.State -ne "Bound"} | select `
 LocalAddress, `
 LocalPort, `
 RemoteAddress, `
 @{name='FQDN';expression={ (Resolve-DnsName -name $_.Remoteaddress).NameHost}},`
 RemotePort, `
 @{n="PID";e={$_.OwningProcess}}, @{n="ProcessName";e={($obj |? PID -eq $_.OwningProcess | select -ExpandProperty ProcessName)}}, `
 @{n="UserName";e={($obj |? PID -eq $_.OwningProcess | select -ExpandProperty UserName)}}, `
 "State","CreationTime"|
 sort -Property ProcessName, UserName

 $Report += $Connections
$Connections=@()
 $Reported = $Report | Sort-Object -Property * -Unique
 $Report = $Reported




$Report |Export-Csv -Path C:\PATH\Connections.csv
```